# Find process id by window's handle

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a problem with getting a specific PID of a process,
the problem with this process is that it's a hidden process, it's not showing on task manager / PowerShell, completely hidden.

What I have so far is the main window handle of this process, the question is, how can I get the pid of it.

What I'm trying to do is to read the memory of this process and edit it, but can't do so without the PID I guess (since I need to get it's base address in memory).

So, if anyone has any workaround or something for me, it will be great.

P.S: this process does not show in `Process.GetProcesses()`.

ty!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use the following Windows API:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint processId);
```

You pass in the HWND and use the out parameter to return the PID.

You can read more on this function [here on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid).

Answer (score 10):

You will need to use P/invoke with the Windows API.

Declare a function in your class like

```
 [DllImport("User32.dll")]
 static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
```

and then call it in your class.

See [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowthreadprocessid).

Comment: This one actually returns 0, not working for me but thanks for responding.