# Sending keys to an open windows in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I made a program that opens a certain program, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it after x amount of time.

I am now using this `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{c}")`. 
Will this target that certain window or just randomly send it to the current window?

How can I change it to a certain window?

This is my code:

```
Write-Host "Safe Botting V0.1"
Write-Host "Initializing..."
Start-Sleep -s 3
Write-Host "Program started successfully with no errors."

While($true)
{
    Write-Host "Starting bot..."
    Start-Sleep -s 3
    Start-Process -FilePath E:\Documents\bot.exe
    Write-Host "Bot started successfully"
    $rnd = Get-Random -Minimum 1800 -Maximum 10800
    Write-Host "The bot will run for:"
    Write-Host $rnd
    Start-Sleep -s $rnd
    Write-Host "Bot will now stop!"
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{c}") 
    Write-Host "Bot terminated"
    Write-Host "Starting cooldown time"
    $rnb = Get-Random -Minimum 14400 -Maximum 28800
    Write-Host "The bot will cooldown for"
    Write-host $rnb
    Start-Sleep -s $rnb
    Write-Host "Cooldown Finished, Restarting"
    Start-Sleep -s 5
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); I suspect there's a cleaner solution to your problem, e.g. using the `Taskkill` command. Also, please include your actual code in your post.

Comment: The program im trying to run has to be stopped by Ctrl+C or else it will fail to load next time.

Comment: Then how about the [`Stop-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177004.aspx) command?

Comment: Im not so familliar with powerhshell what does Stop-Process do?

Comment: Click the link in the above comment. I'm not going to copy+paste the first paragraph here.

Comment: Will Stop-Process close it as if i Ctrl  + C ?

Comment: Please go and try it yourself. We're not here to spoon-feed you a solution.

Comment: Ok, so after doing some testing i managed to do this.

Comment: $botid = Start-Process -FilePath E:\Documents\bot.exe -PassThru

Comment: Then i do this taskkill /PID $botid.id

Comment: But the problem is it closes it, and then the program cant save like it did with Ctrl + C

Comment: Please look into this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017094/handling-a-popup-box-using-powershell They describe here how to activate required window to send your key sequence to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could send the CTRL_C_EVENT signal to the process if you have the process id. In your case you can get that from Start-Process (read the docs if you don't know how to get the process id). It's also possible to get the process id from a Window Handle:

[Find process id by window's handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184654/find-process-id-by-windows-handle)

Sending the signal is non trivial, but thanks to @Nemo1024, @KindDragon, and Stack Overflow it's been worked out:

[Can I send a ctrl-C (SIGINT) to an application on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows)

Unfortunately, using the best approach I could find also terminated the calling PowerShell process and the only workaround I could come up with was to send the signal from a fresh PowerShell instance that I launch.

In PowerShell it looks something like this:

```
# be sure to set $ProcessID properly. Sending CTRL_C_EVENT signal can disrupt or terminate a process
$ProcessID = 1234
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("Add-Type -Names 'w' -Name 'k' -M '[DllImport(""kernel32.dll"")]public static extern bool FreeConsole();[DllImport(""kernel32.dll"")]public static extern bool AttachConsole(uint p);[DllImport(""kernel32.dll"")]public static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(uint h, bool a);[DllImport(""kernel32.dll"")]public static extern bool GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(uint e, uint p);public static void SendCtrlC(uint p){FreeConsole();AttachConsole(p);GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(0, 0);}';[w.k]::SendCtrlC($ProcessID)"))
start-process powershell.exe -argument "-nologo -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -EncodedCommand $encodedCommand"
```

Yes, I know this is VERY ugly.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [jimhark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514485/jimhark), I found a way to make it work without spawning a separate PowerShell process to send the Ctrl-C. It works if the PowerShell process sending the Ctrl-C also spawned, using for example Start-Process, the process it is sending the Ctrl-C to:

```
$ProcessID = 1234
$MemberDefinition = '
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]public static extern bool FreeConsole();
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]public static extern bool AttachConsole(uint p);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]public static extern bool GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(uint e, uint p);
    public static void SendCtrlC(uint p) {
        FreeConsole();
        AttachConsole(p);
        GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(0, p);
        FreeConsole();
        AttachConsole(uint.MaxValue);
    }'
Add-Type -Name 'dummyName' -Namespace 'dummyNamespace' -MemberDefinition $MemberDefinition
[dummyNamespace.dummyName]::SendCtrlC($ProcessID) }
```

What made things work was sending the [GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/generateconsolectrlevent) to the desired process group instead of `all processes that share the console of the calling process` and [AttachConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole) back to `the console of the parent of the current process`.

Comment: Nice. And more readable. I've not tested this, but it looks good.